# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error while installing app android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am facing the INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error when trying to install my app.

I have gone through all the solutions available for this error on stack overflow. There is no capital letter in my mainfest file package name.

Can anyone point out what might be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.punchtech">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:name="com.punchtech.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/new_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/LoginTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.login_signup.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.punchtech.login_signup.Login_signup_Mainscreen" />

        <activity android:name="com.punchtech.login_signup.Login_screen" />

        <activity android:name="com.punchtech.login_signup.Signup_screen" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.Bottombar_main"
            android:theme="@style/ForFragment"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity android:name="com.punchtech.Main_Post" />

        <activity android:name="com.punchtech.User_profile_all.Jump_userProfile" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.CreatePunch.image_search_api"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.CreatePunch.Tag_selection_create_punch"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.CreatePunch.Create_punch"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.CreatePunch.select_Community"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.Home_communiy_all.tag_selection_main"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.User_profile_all.setting_user_profile"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.User_profile_all.user_profile_follow"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.User_profile_all.user_profile_edit"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity android:name="com.punchtech.Home_communiy_all.community_view_home_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.Comment_all.Comment_post"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.punchtech.Home_communiy_all.Create_Community_main"
            android:theme="@style/create_community" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have an opening `<manifest>` tag?

Comment: yup i have the tag added

Comment: so please edit your question with the **complete** identical manifest from your project

Comment: ok I edited the file contents

Comment: I am not sure if `<meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" />` is correct and I think a value or resource is needed for meta-data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your meta data is incorrect:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" />
```

As stated in the api a meta-data tag is a name-value pair and needs a value or resource. It must be for example:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
android:value="@string/yourValue" />
```

or

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:resource="@string/yourValue" />
```

Change this, delete your app from device, clean project and reinstall it.

Comment: thanks! I changed that particular tag to....`<meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:value="true"/>`